# Coding about Diffusion with connection Time

Tags: java

I have a long list of logs that contains "Time | ID_node1 | ID_node2 | ConnectionUP or ConnectionDown" and this will be my input.

The output that I want is list of Connected node starting with Initial node that I select. I know that coding these kind of programs are not hard. There are few RULES for nodes to be in the Connected list:

1. There are some group of initial active nodes.
2. The node that connects with the initial nodes will be "active node".
3. Once the node becomes an active node, it can make others as active.
4. Connection time has to be at least n seconds to become an active node.

So far I can get the list of connected list when "Initial Active Nodes" are the only group that make other node active. However, I am having trouble when I add a rule "active node also can make other nodes active."

Here is the Example that can help you to understand:

1.0 p1 p3 UP

1.0 p4 p6 UP

1.0 p2 p5 UP

2.0 p2 p5 DOWN

2.0 P5 p8 UP

3.0 p5 p6 DOWN

7.0 p3 P8 UP

12.0 p3 p8 DOWN

13.0 p1 p3 DOWN

If "P1" is the initial active node, by Time = 12.0, List of Connected Node should contain {p1, p3, p8} because p3 became active node when t = 6.

As you can see, number of logs for each seconds is different. So right now I am thinking about:

```
List L1: Node1ID | Node2ID | Int 

for (int i = 1, i <= t, i++) {

  if L1 isEmpty()
    JUST GO TO line 15
  if L1 isNotEmpty()
    ADD 1 to Int section
    Check L1 contains 5 on Int section
  if do()
    ADD two nodes in ListofConnectedNode 
    Delete Duplicate in ListofConnectedNode
    Also delete in L1

  readALL log that has i
  if Log contains UP, 
    ADD to List:L1 that has (Node1ID & Node2ID, 1)
  if Log contains DOWN, 
    DELETE the list that contains both nodeIDs

}
```

Do you guys think this would work in JAVA? Or is there any better way to implement what I want?

Comment: what do you mean by this line `if do()`? is do() a function of some sort?

Comment: Oh, sorry, it means "If L1 contains 5 on Int section"

Comment: I don't understand the question - why shouldn't you be able to write this logic in Java?